# Which guilds are there in "Nightwings" by Robert Silverberg, and what are their purposes?

Tags: novella, robert-silverberg

I really liked reading *[Nightwings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightwings_(novella))*, especially for the world created there. I liked the idea of inherent guild membership due to past modifications, etc. I would like to take my RPG or LARP players there once in a while, but to do so, I would need to know which guilds are there to choose from.

Has someone compiled a list of such guilds? I only have a Polish translation, so re-reading it to compile it on my own would be inaccurate at best, and a bit tedious.

Comment: Didn't read it but here is a list: "Watchers, Defender Rememberers, Clowns,
Musicians, Somnambulists, Scribes, Servitors, Merchants,
Dominators, and the like. In addition, there are new biological forms
mixed in with these groups: Changelings and Fliers and assorted
visitors from outer space—a whole society creatively re-imagined by
our author." Quote from this link. http://www.conceptualfiction.com/nightwings.html Somebody who read it should probably write a proper answer.

Answer (score 9):

Only a partial list can be made, since there are a lot of guilds never mentioned.

> Gormon said, "And today, how many guilds are there?"
>
> Discomfited, Basil replied vaguely, "At least a hundred, my friend. Some are quite small; some are local. I am concerned only with the original guilds and their immediate successors; what has happened in the past few hundred years is in the province of others. Shall I requisition an information for you?"

That said a fair number of guilds, including most of the important ones, are mentioned in the story.

Existing guilds:

- Watchers - guild that watches the sky for signs of invasion
- Rememberers - guild of those who investigate, record and remember history
- Fliers - guild of gene-modified humans who can fly
- Defenders - guild of those sworn defend Earth against invasion
- Masters - guild of overseers and managers
- Pilgrims - guild of those driven to travel to Jorslem, commune with the Will
- Sentinel - guild of gate-keepers and police
- Merchants - guild that buys, transports and sells goods
- Vendors - guild of shop-keepers
- Servitors - guild of servants
- Manufactories - guild of craftsmen/builders
- Scribes
- Communicants - guild of interpreters of the Will (likened to poets in some ways)
- Transporters
- Clowns - guild of entertainers
- Indexers - guild to organize knowledge, keep track of people
- Musicians
- Landholders
- Dominators - guild of leaders/rulers; can also join multiple guilds
- Somnambulists - guild of people who claim to see what has been, what is, and what will be
- Chronomancers - guild that forecasts coming events
- Artificers - guild that makes small complex devices, like artificial eyes
- Surgeon - guild for all healers and doctors
- Swimmers - guild of modified water-adapted humans (no longer heard from)
- Renewers - guild that performs the process of Renewal
- Redeemers - guild formed to help shape humanity's rebirth

No longer a guild:

- Changelings - all gene-modded humans not in another guild, their guild disbanded after they tried to seize Jorslem

Other (likely extinct) gene-mods:

- Twiners
- Burners
- Climbers

Other categories:

- guildless - people who have not yet joined a guild, such as after renewal
- neuters - criminals and others punished by being turned into labour devices
- outworlders - any non-human being

Answer (score 8):

From a quick readthrough:

- Fliers - flies with wings
- Watchers - watches the skies with instruments for "the enemies of man"
- Rememberer - seem to be historians and archaeologists
- Defenders - defense of the Earth
- Masters - seem to be some sort of leadership
- Pilgrims - seem to do religious pilgrimages, commune with "the Will". They are blinded and wear a mask.
- Sentinels - city guards
- Merchants - seem to be, well, merchants
- Vendors
- Servitors
- Manufactories
- Scribes
- Communicants - ask for spiritual guidance about the outcome of events, presumably from "the Will"
- Transporters
- Clowns - entertainers
- Indexers - seem to guard the doors to the palace and tabernacle, indicated in the sequel that they make records for the Rememberers without understanding
- Landholders
- Dominators - higher, possibly aristocratic, leadership, can take up multiple guilds
- Musicians
- Somnambulists - something involving trances, and selling that experience, sometimes speaking for "the Will". They claim to be able to see the past, present, and future, and seem to have a degree of actual clairvoyance.
- Chronomancers - diviners of the future

Not a guild now:

- Changelings - Those deformed by teratogenic drugs. Originally, they were a guild.

Never a guild:

- Neuters

From the sequel, "Perris Way":

- Artificers - able to create artificial eyes at the least
- Surgeons
- Swimmers - an altered race like the Fliers who have been lost to antiquity

Comment: I was confused by your mention of a "sequel", but discovered that depending on the edition, "Nightwings" can refer either to the first of three novellas, or the "fixup" novel combining all three.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware that there was a third one. :)